# How to sort multiple columns using laravel, mongo and datatables?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, datatables, laravel-5.4

I have a project in laravel. Database is mongodb. I am using a package to connect using laravel and mongo "https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb". In my project I have a bookings listing page. jQuery Datatables server side feature is using for pagination, search and sort. At-present pagination and searching is working but sorting is not working. I am getting some error, Please check the attachment. I thing it's a problem in sort section in query. Please check below codes and help me. Thanks.

**bookings.blade.php**

```
$('#booking_data').DataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": '{{ route('bookings.datatables') }}',
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "data":{ _token: "{{csrf_token()}}"}
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "hash" },
                    { "data": "invoice_number" },
                    { "data": "usrEmail" },
                    { "data": "checkin_from" },
                    { "data": "reserve_to" },
                    { "data": "beds" },
                    { "data": "dormitory" },
                    { "data": "sleeps" },
                    { "data": "status" },
                    { "data": "payment_status" },
                    { "data": "payment_type" },
                    { "data": "total_prepayment_amount" },
                    { "data": "txid" }
                ]
            });
```

**BookingController.php**

```
public function dataTables(Request $request)
    {
        $columns       = array('invoice_number', 'checkin_from', 'reserve_to', 'beds', 'dormitory', 'sleeps', 'status', 'payment_status', 'payment_type', 'total_prepayment_amount', 'txid');

        $totalData     = Booking::where('is_delete', 0)->count();

        $totalFiltered = $totalData;
        $limit         = (int)$request->input('length');
        $start         = (int)$request->input('start');
        $order         = $columns[$request->input('order.0.column')];
        $dir           = $request->input('order.0.dir');

        if(empty($request->input('search.value')))
        {
            $bookings = Booking::select('invoice_number', 'temp_user_id', 'user', 'checkin_from', 'reserve_to', 'beds', 'dormitory', 'sleeps', 'status', 'payment_status', 'payment_type', 'total_prepayment_amount', 'txid')
                ->where('is_delete', 0)
                ->skip($start)
                ->take($limit)
                ->orderBy($order, $dir)
                ->get();
        }
        else {
            $search   = $request->input('search.value');
            $bookings = Booking::select('invoice_number', 'temp_user_id', 'user', 'checkin_from', 'reserve_to', 'beds', 'dormitory', 'sleeps', 'status', 'payment_status', 'payment_type', 'total_prepayment_amount', 'txid')
                ->where('is_delete', 0)
                ->where(function($query) use ($search) { 
                    $query->where('invoice_number', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('payment_type', 'like', "%{$search}%");
                })
                ->skip($start)
                ->take($limit)
                ->orderBy($order, $dir)
                ->get();

            $totalFiltered = Booking::select('invoice_number', 'temp_user_id', 'user', 'checkin_from', 'reserve_to', 'beds', 'dormitory', 'sleeps', 'status', 'payment_status', 'payment_type', 'total_prepayment_amount', 'txid')
                ->where('is_delete', 0)
                ->where(function($query) use ($search) {
                    $query->where('invoice_number', 'like', "%{$search}%")
                        ->orWhere('payment_type', 'like', "%{$search}%");
                })
                ->count();
        }

        $data = array();
        if(!empty($bookings))
        {
            foreach ($bookings as $key=> $booking)
            {
                $nestedData['hash']                    = '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="'.$booking->_id.'" />';
                $nestedData['invoice_number']          = '<a class="nounderline modalBooking" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bookingModal_'.$booking->_id.'" data-modalID="'.$booking->_id.'">'.$booking->invoice_number.'</a>';
                $nestedData['usrEmail']                = $booking->user;
                $nestedData['checkin_from']            = ($booking->checkin_from)->format('d.m.y');
                $nestedData['reserve_to']              = ($booking->reserve_to)->format('d.m.y');
                $nestedData['beds']                    = $booking->beds;
                $nestedData['dormitory']               = $booking->dormitory;
                $nestedData['sleeps']                  = $booking->sleeps;
                $nestedData['status']                  = $booking->status;
                $nestedData['payment_status']          = $booking->payment_status;
                $nestedData['payment_type']            = $booking->payment_type;
                $nestedData['total_prepayment_amount'] = $booking->total_prepayment_amount;
                $nestedData['txid']                    = $booking->txid;
                $data[]                                = $nestedData;
            }
        }

        $json_data = array(
            'draw'            => (int)$request->input('draw'),
            'recordsTotal'    => (int)$totalData,
            'recordsFiltered' => (int)$totalFiltered,
            'data'            => $data
        );

        echo json_encode($json_data);
}
```

[image: please check the image attached] .

Comment: Could you please tell which one is line 46 in your controller ?

Comment: We miss some info: what url do you call, what is on line 46 exactly, what does your route look like, what middleware is used, what does the table look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here in your `BookingController`.

```
$columns       = array('invoice_number', 'checkin_from', 'reserve_to', 'beds', 'dormitory', 'sleeps', 'status', 'payment_status', 'payment_type', 'total_prepayment_amount', 'txid');
...
$order         = $columns[$request->input('order.0.column')];
```

DataTable will send the column name in the request, not the `key` so you can't use it that way. Maybe you can replace with this:

```
$order = $request->input('order.0.column');
```

If you want to validate against your valid columns you can use the `in_array()` function.

Comment: `order[0][column]` request parameter is a zero-based column index, see [Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Sent-parameters), so `$columns[$request->input('order.0.column')]` seems like a valid way to do it.